# How can I make the browser wait to display the page until it's fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, css

I hate how you can actually see webpages load.  I think it'd be much more appealing to wait until the page is fully loaded and ready to be displayed, including all scripts and images, and then have the browser display it.  So I have two questions:

1. How can I do this?
2. Is this common practice?  If not, why?

Comment: I dislike how some pages don't show anything until everything is loaded. Don't make the mistake to assume that the users think the same way you do.

Comment: Facebook does this, and it just pisses me off.

Comment: If you do this, at least make sure you display a message right away saying the page is loading..

Comment: You say you hate seeing the page load. I do too, sometimes - if the content jumps around while it's loading. You can minimize this by setting explicit sizes for your images, so that the browser knows how large a space to leave for them and doesn't have to move the text to accommodate them when they load.

Comment: But in my case, my navbar reloads the images that make it up every time you change pages, and it looks terrible when the page it re-constructed every couple seconds when you click a link.

Comment: @tkbx A good idea would be to use caching with HTML5 for those elements so the "frame" loads nearly instantly. **For those who are interested on making it look less choppy and more professional, static page content should be done this way.** You could even cache a script with a loading bar where large chunks of dynamic content goes, like your body. As long as you don't need to support IE9 (not sure about 10) this is a good alternative. Just make sure to have some way to send with each page a "framework version number" or whatever so you can trigger the cache to be cleared.

Comment: To wait for CSS only, check [Nate Bunney's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22767958/3258851) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172281/3258851).

Answer (score 38):

This is a very bad idea for all of the reasons given, and more. That said, here's how you do it using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
<body>
<div id="msg" style="font-size:largest;">
<!-- you can set whatever style you want on this -->
Loading, please wait...
</div>
<div id="body" style="display:none;">
<!-- everything else -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#body').show();
    $('#msg').hide();
});
</script>
</body>
```

If the user has JavaScript disabled, they never see the page. If the page never finishes loading, they never see the page. If the page takes too long to load, they may assume something went wrong and just go elsewhere instead of *please wait...*ing.

Comment: One way of getting around the no javascript issue with this solution would be to make use of the `<noscript>` tags to "undo" the `display:none` effect.

Comment: I had to use `$(window)` instead of `$(document)`.

Answer (score 20):

I think this is a really bad idea.  Users like to see progress, plain and simple.  Keeping the page at one state for a few seconds and then instantly displaying the loaded page will make the user feel like nothing is happening and you are likely to lose visits.

One option is to show a loading status on your page while stuff processes in the background, but this is normally reserved for when the site is actually doing processing on user input.

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=180958

The bottom line, you at least need to show some visual activity while the page is loading, and I think having the page load in little pieces at a time is not all that bad (assuming you aren't doing something that seriously slows down page load time).

Comment: I designed a site that uses a lightweight spinner while heavy things are loading - the heavy things are set to `display: none`. Once everything is loaded, the spinner fades out and the content fades in. It works well since a spinner is now universally understood as *"loading, please wait"*. Note: It uses jQuery.

Comment: I think it's unfair to generalize like that. If you're building a really fast and snappy website, then boy is it annoying that the browser decides to ruin the experience by displaying several frames of an unfinished rendered website. I think we should strive for better website and better user experiences. 

I'm not saying the fix is a good fix, I would much rather have that browsers waited until it was done processing. And then it's up to website to make sure that their shit is well optimized and loads fast. We shouldn't build systems so programmers can get away with lazy and bad behaviour.

Comment: Key here is whether your page design overrides in-browser signaling of page load. Browsers have always had a signal to show whether a page is still loading. Modern browsers show it with an animated loading icon for each tab, so you can even see if a tab is fully loaded in the background. Best practice is to ensure that, however your page loads, you respect that signaling. Any page design that signals to the browser that the page is fully loaded, when it's not, is likely to mislead and annoy users. On-page signaling is useless for tabs opened in the background if the browser says it's loaded.

Answer (score 13):

There is certainly a valid use for this.  One is to prevent people from clicking on links/causing JavaScript events to occur until all the page elements and JavaScript have loaded.

In **IE**, you could use page transitions which mean the page doesn't display until it's fully loaded:

```
<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(Duration=.01)" />
<meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="blendTrans(Duration=.01)" />
```

Notice the short duration.  It's just enough to make sure the page doesn't display until it's fully loaded.

In **FireFox** and other browsers, the solution I've used is to create a DIV that is the size of the page and white, then at the very end of the page put in JavaScript that hides it.  Another way would be to use jQuery and hide it as well.  Not as painless as the IE solution but both work well.

Comment: For the firefox solution: what about users who disabled javascript?

Comment: @ChristopheD Answer: those 10 people in the world who turn off javascript will not be able to see the page.

Comment: @ChristopheD It seems like a lot of things are reliant on JS so [at least for my site] it wouldn't function correctly anyway.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a solution using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#container').css('opacity', 0);
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#container').css('opacity', 1);
});
</script>
```

I put this script just after my `</body>` tag. Just replace "#container" with a selector for the DOM element(s) you want to hide. I tried several variations of this (including `.hide()`/`.show()`, and `.fadeOut()`/`.fadeIn()`), and just setting the opacity seems to have the fewest ill effects (flicker, changing page height, etc.). You can also replace `css('opacity', 0)` with `fadeTo(100, 1)` for a smoother transition. (No, `fadeIn()` won't work, at least not under jQuery 1.3.2.)

Now the caveats: I implemented the above because I'm using TypeKit and there's an annoying flicker when you refresh the page and the fonts take a few hundred milliseconds to load. So I don't want any text to appear on the screen until TypeKit has loaded. But obviously you're in big trouble if you use the code above and something on your page fails to load. There are two obvious ways that it could be improved:

1. A maximum time limit (say, 1 second) after which everything appears whether the page is loaded or not
2. Some kind of loading indicator (say, something from http://www.ajaxload.info/)

I won't bother implementing the loading indicator here, but the time limit is easy. Just add this to the script above:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout('$("#container").css("opacity", 1)', 1000);
});
```

So now, worst-case scenario, your page will take an extra second to appear.

Comment: It flickers because you hide the page using JS. I think it's better to hide it with pure CSS. JavaScript's job: remove the display:none once page fully loaded.

Answer (score 6):

Immediately following your <body> tag add something like this...

```
 <style> body  {opacity:0;}</style>
```

And for the very first thing in your <head> add something like...

```
 <script>
  window.onload = function() {setTimeout(function(){document.body.style.opacity="100";},500);};
 </script>
```

As far as this being good practice or bad depends on your visitors, and the time the wait takes.

The question that is stil left open and I am not seeing any answers here is how to be sure the page has stabilized. For example if you are loading fonts the page may reflow a bit until all the fonts are loaded and displayed. I would like to know if there is an event that tells me the page is done rendering.

Answer (score 4):

Also make sure the server buffers the page and does not *immediately* (while building) stream it to the client browser.

Since you have not specified your technology stack:

- PHP: look into [ob_start](http://be.php.net/ob_start)
- ASP.NET: make sure Response.BufferOutput = True (it is by default)

Comment: note that while this will help when sending huge dynamically built html pages, this will not work for 'external' linked images and scripts/stylesheets (but those will be in the browser cache after the first page load anyway)

Answer (score 3):

obligatory: "use jQuery"

I've seen pages that put a black or white div that covers everything on top of the page, then remove it on the document.load event. Or you could use .ready in jQuery **That being said, it was one of the most anoying web pages I've ever seen, I would advise against it**.

Answer (score 3):

in PHP-Fusion Open Source CMS, http://www.php-fusion.co.uk, we do it this way at core -

```
    <?php
        ob_start();
        // Your PHP codes here            
        ?>
        YOUR HTML HERE


        <?php 
        $html_output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        echo $html_output;
    ?>
```

You won't be able to see anything loading one by one. The only loader will be your browser tab spinner, and it just displays everything in an instant after everything is loaded. Give it a try.

This method is fully compliant in html files.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide everything using some css:

```
#some_div
{
  display: none;
}
```

and then in javascript assign a function to document.onload to remove that div.

jQuery makes things like this very easy.

Comment: Of course, if the user doesn't have javascript, they'll never see your page.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Trevor Burnham's answer if you want to deal with [disabled javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724515/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-html-no-js-class) and [defer css loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374843/css-delivery-optimization-how-to-defer-css-loading)

**HTML5**

```
<html class="no-js">

    <head>...</head>

    <body>

        <header>...</header>

        <main>...</main>

        <footer>...</footer>

    </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
//at the beginning of the page

    .js main, .js footer{

        opacity:0;

    }
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
//at the beginning of the page before loading jquery

    var h = document.querySelector("html");

    h.className += ' ' + 'js';

    h.className = h.className.replace(
    new RegExp('( |^)' + 'no-js' + '( |$)', 'g'), ' ').trim();
```

**JQUERY**

```
//somewhere at the end of the page after loading jquery

        $(window).load(function() {

            $('main').css('opacity',1);
            $('footer').css('opacity',1);

        });
```

**RESOURCES**

- [CSS delivery optimization: How to defer css loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374843/css-delivery-optimization-how-to-defer-css-loading)
- [What is the purpose of the HTML "no-js" class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724515/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-html-no-js-class)
- [How to get the <html> tag HTML with JavaScript / jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196971/how-to-get-the-html-tag-html-with-javascript-jquery/14593048)
- [How to add/remove a class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787383/how-to-add-remove-a-class-in-javascript/27213779)

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with the others that you should not want it I'll just briefly explain what you can do to make a small difference without going all the way and actually *blocking* content that is already there -- maybe this will be enough to keep both you and your visitors happy.

The browser starts loading a page and will process externally located css and js later, especially if the place the css/js is linked is at the 'correct' place. (I think the advice is to load js as late as possible, and to use external css that you load in the header). Now if you have some portion of your css and/or js that you would like to be applied as soon as possible simply include that in the page itself. This will be against the advice of performance tools like YSlow but it probably will increase the change of your page showing up like you want it to be shown. Use this only when really needed!

Answer (score 0):

You could start by having your site's main index page contain only a message saying "Loading". From here you could use ajax to fetch the contents of your next page and embed it into the current one, on completion removing the "Loading" message.

You might be able to get away with just including a loading message container at the top of your page which is 100% width/height and then removing the said div on load complete.

The latter may not work perfectly in both situations and will depends on how the browser renders content.

I'm not entirely sure if its a good idea. For simple static sites I would say not. However, I have seen a lot of heavy javascript sites lately from design companies that use complex animation and are one page. These sites use a loading message to wait for all scripts/html/css to be loaded so that the page functions as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use display:none. If you do, you will see images resize/reposition when you do the show(). Use visibility:hidden instead and it will lay everything out correctly, but it just won't be visible until you tell it to.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will help

```
 <html>  
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
          .js #flash {display: none;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          document.documentElement.className = 'js';
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <!-- the rest of your code goes here -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          // Stuff to do as soon as the body finishes loading.
          // No need for $(document).ready() here.
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am, frankly, a bit disturbed at many of the answers here. I'd say all of them are terrible. Although I share the skeptical reaction of the various top respondents, many answers give "solutions" that won't display anything at all to a user who has JavaScript disabled, and many others rely on a customized on-page loading notice, while signaling to the browser that the page is already loaded.

As a user, I hate both of these outcomes, so as a web-developer, I'd say these are both "non-solutions". You never want to anger your userbase and the solutions given here will anger a lot of users. I especially hate these approaches because if the user opens a webpage in the background in a new tab, the browser will display the page as loaded but the user might click over to it to find that it isn't loaded.

Independently of your question here, best practice is to make as much of your site work without JavaScript as possible, and best practice is to use the browser's built-in loading signals and never signal to the browser that the page is loaded before it actually is. So really, the only good way to do this is to make your page load so fast that there is never any moment of the user waiting.

The best way to achieve what you want is avoid use of Javascript to load elements of the page, and then optimize the page intensely. Here are the components of this approach:

- Have JavaScript on the page if you like, but don't use it to load or otherwise modify any DOM elements after the initial request is fulfilled by the server. Use JavaScript to modify elements of the page *only later*, such as if triggered by user input, or perhaps to refresh an element after some time, but not in any way related to the page's initial loading. I.e. use JavaScript for what it was designed for (to make webpages interactive) and don't use it to do what HTML was designed for (to make the webpage in the first place.)
- Avoid the use of any heavy JavaScript libraries and include as little JavaScript as possible. Never include JavaScript files generically, i.e. only include specific files / libraries in specific pages where you need them.
- Specify the width and height of any images in the page code itself, so that the browser can know the exact layout before the image loaded. This reduces any "choppiness" as the page loads, i.e. elements moving around as the browser resizes the boxes in which images of unspecified width are contained.
- Ensure that image files are in the exact dimensions being displayed on the page and are not being downsized by the browser. This minimizes file size and also minimizes CPU work the user's computer needs to do to resize images, both of which can affect load time.
- Optimize the compression of images, which includes using a good lossy format like JPG and lowering the compression level to as low as you can go without affecting perception. Use lossless formats like PNG only where necessary and ideally keep them small in dimension so the filesize is also small.
- Focus the intensity of your optimization efforts on any elements that load "above the fold" on a typical page, as these are what is going to affect what the user sees. Users rarely scroll down instantly, so if elements lower down on the page load a bit slower, almost no one will notice. But still optimize these lower elements reasonably because they also affect server load, bandwidth, and user CPU load.
- If you use any elements at all in your page that are potentially very slow to load due to reasons beyond your control, such as content pulled from another server (ads, social media widgets, integrations with other websites, etc.), compartmentalize these in an element of fixed size, and ideally place it below the fold.
- Avoid auto-ads, page-modifying AI (like Ezoic), or any other external add-ins that necessarily breaks or undermines one or more of these recommendations. For example, auto-ads are terrible because they rely on loading an external resource,they usually have heavy javascript libraries, and they also modify the page layout. Even the best-designed auto-ads are going to completely undermine all your other optimization efforts.
- If you are running a company with multiple developers, quickly jettison any developers who are not fully committed to a lightweight, fast-loading web design. Ideally, don't ever hire such people to begin with. A lot of people get really vested in a certain philosophy or style of development that is at odds with lightweight design. The world would be a better place if these people were in a different line of work, rather than designing webpages.

So you've optimized your page.

This produces the outcome that, if the user clicks the link directly, they'll see the content above the fold fully loaded immediately or nearly-immediately, worst-case-scenario being that a couple images fill in in a second or two. By the time they scroll down, everything else will already be loaded. Any truly-slow-to-load content, such as Google Analytics tracking or other third-party services, will not be central to the appearance of the webpage itself, so the user will see a fully-loaded page even if there are still a few invisible elements loading behind the scenes.

On the other hand, if the user loads the link in a background tab, it will display as loading to the browser, showing the animated symbol in the tab, until it is truly fully loaded. Once it displays as loaded in the tab, if they click it, it will be fully loaded.

In addition, you will have made the page load really fast, which is a good thing in and of itself.

This is a win-win. The user sees a full-loaded page nearly instantly, there is almost never any waiting while looking at a half-displayed page, the loading symbol works as expected when loading a tab in the background, and on top of this you've netted a ton of side-benefits like reduced bandwidth and server CPU load, not to mention lessening the load on the user's CPU as well. (Many users HATE when your page cranks their CPU, and rightfully so.)

So yeah, your choice what to do, but there is only one real solution here and it is lightweight, efficient web design.

Answer (score 0):

Put text at the top of the page. While the user reads it, the rest of the page can load and it will be ready by the time the user scrolls down.