# How to prevent flickering when loading a webpage?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I am learning how to create webpages and I made a simple one that runs on a python server, locally, on y machine. I have a menu that can be pressed to re-direct to other sections, essentially loading a new page.

On the half a second it takes to load the page, the raw html is visible until the CSS formatting is applied, which looks really ugly. I want to know if there is a way to prevent the new page from being displayed until it is ready, or at least add a blank, black, page over the html until the CSS is ready.

I am using flask for the server:

from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="/static", static_folder="/static")

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route("/resume")
def resume():
    return render_template("resume.html")
```

And this is how the buttons look in html:

```
<nav id="PageNav">
    <div id="TimeContainer">
        <ul id="TimeList">
            <li><a href="/"><span>Home<span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/resume"><span>Resume<span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Math<span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22767958/4675937).

Comment: Don't know where you load css file, but try to put it as first child of HEAD element.