# how to fix the running order between html and css files?

Tags: html, css, runtime, loading

I have placed the css links into a separate page and include the page into the html file, in running time the html shows without the css design for 1 second then the page load correctly.

I am using Atom application and Laravel framework. I have reformat the css by removing the unnecessary lines and merge the codes in one line.

[image: plaintext of html file]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force browsers to load CSS before showing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172281/force-browsers-to-load-css-before-showing-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

In order to load the css styling before the html, you have got to include the css file in the header of the html.

Comment: Yes, true, except OP could still be doing this and the styling could be applied after the initial DOM render.

Comment: Please check out the link in my comment on the original post.

Comment: @rb612 the link you provide, solve the problem by only hiding the html file by a background color for awhile until css load.