# Error:Displaying html content for a fraction of a second before loading up dynamic page

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

I have issue in my project in Eclipse.I have Dynamic Web Project which consists of jsp,html and javascript files in it.It displays html content for a fraction of second before loading actual html content with js and CSS ad ons. I couldn't find issue in the code.Is there anything I am missing?
This is the order in which I have included all my css and js files:

```
<html>
<head>
<style><%@include file="/WEB-INF/style.css"%></style>
<style><%@include file="/WEB-INF/jquery-ui.css"%></style>
<style><%@include file="/WEB-INF/jqueryui-com.css"%></style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-KM512VNnjElC30ehFwehXjx1YCHPiQkOPmqnrWtpccM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/file.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172281/force-browsers-to-load-css-before-showing-the-page Have you tried this

Comment: @Silverfang The error still persists

Comment: did you added your css and js file under `<head>` tag ?

Comment: @Swati yes I had