# Disable preload in Vite

Tags: vue.js, vite

I'm migrating a big project that uses Vue 2 and Webpack to Vue 3 and Vite. Everything looks great so far, however when we released to production in our first try we noticed that there were MANY module preload tags injected and many of the files there would probably never be used.

The question is, how can I disable preload project wise? If not possible, is there a way to telling Vite some of the imports that it should never preload?

A use case for not preloading is a mocker file which is dynamically imported only in development environment, however it's referred in the code. Since it's lazy loaded I wouldn't have problem with Webpack on this, but Vite is acting ahead of time with optimizations and including everything it finds.

Example from our codebase:

```js
export const fetchData = createGetService({
  url: '/example-endpoint',
  mocker: async () => (await import('./example.mocker')).mockExample(),
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since **Vite** `3.1` we have a configuration option for controlling the preload.

```js
// vite.config.js

import {defineConfig} from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
    ...
    build: {
        // Disables the preload.
        modulePreload: false,

        // Or you can specify what should be preloaded.
        modulePreload: {
            resolveDependencies(url, deps, context) {
                return [] // Your list of preloaded deps.
            },
        },
    },
})
```

It is documented inside the [configuration section](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-modulepreload) on the Vite web site.

More technical details can be found on the [Pull Request](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/9938) implementing the feature.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the correct to do when the answer changes with time, should I mark yours as the answer or suggest the original one to update with yours?

Answer (score 2):

There's [currently no official way to disable preloads in the build](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/3133).

A workaround is to use a Vite plugin that removes the unwanted preloads from the built `index.html` via [the `transformIndexHtml` hook](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#transformindexhtml):

```js
// plugins/removePreloads.js
export default ({ filter = () => false } = {}) => ({
  name: 'remove-preloads',
  enforce: 'post',
  transformIndexHtml(html) {
    return html.replace(
      /\s*(<link rel="(?:module)?preload".*?>)\s*/gi,

      (orig, linkStr) => {
        if (filter(linkStr)) {
          return orig
        }
        console.log('\nremoving ' + linkStr)
        return ''
      }
    )
  },
})
```

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import removePreloads from './remove-preloads'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    // remove all preloads
    removePreloads(),

    // Or remove specific preloads
    removePreloads({
      filter: linkStr => !linkStr.contains('someFilename')
    }),
    ⋮
  ],
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-remove-preloads?file=src/components/HelloWorld.vue)