# How to get the <html> tag HTML with JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using `$('html').html()` I can get the HTML within the `<html>` tag (`<head>`, `<body>`, etc.). But how can I get the actual HTML of the `<html>` tag (with attributes)?

Alternatively, is it possible to get the entire HTML of the page (including doctype, `<html>`, etc.) with jQuery (or plain old JavaScript)?

Answer (score 491, accepted):

The simplest way to get the `html` element natively is:

```
document.documentElement
```

Here's the reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.documentElement.

UPDATE: To then grab the `html` element as a string you would do:

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

Comment: See also this question for more info on `documentElement` browser compatibility: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11391827/177710.

Comment: How often are you getting ref to the html element!? I don't think performance should be a concern, generally. Anyway, this is actually the better answer, but it came in WAY after the award.

Comment: nice, I implemented a brightness slider using this: `<input type="range" min="0.50" max="1.0" value="0.95" step="0.01" onchange= "document.documentElement.style.filter= 'brightness('+this.value+')'">`

Answer (score 55):

This is how to get the html DOM element purely with JS:

```
var htmlElement = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
```

or

```
var htmlElement = document.querySelector("html");
```

And if you want to use jQuery to get attributes from it...

```
$(htmlElement).attr(INSERT-ATTRIBUTE-NAME);
```

Comment: Your answer would be considerably better if you could explain _why_ this answered the question. Also, please highlight code and click the `{}` button or press ctrl + k to mark it up as code.

Answer (score 28):

In addition to some of the other answers, you could also access the HTML element via:

```
var htmlEl = document.body.parentNode;
```

Then you could get the inner HTML content:

```
var inner = htmlEl.innerHTML;
```

Doing so this way seems to be [marginally faster](http://jsperf.com/get-html-element-and-inner).  If you are just obtaining the HTML element, however, `document.body.parentNode` seems to be [quite a bit faster](http://jsperf.com/just-get-html-element).

After you have the HTML element, you can mess with the attributes with the [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getAttribute) and [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute) methods.

For the DOCTYPE, you could use [`document.doctype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.doctype?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.doctype), which was elaborated upon in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088972/get-doctype-of-an-html-as-string-with-javascript).

Comment: Just as a note: This will fail if the body is not yet available on the document.

Comment: In which case, `document.head.parentNode` will still work if there's a head element.

Answer (score 23):

In jQuery:

```
var html_string = $('html').outerHTML()
```

In plain Javascript:

```
var html_string = document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

Answer (score 4):

if you want to get an attribute of an HTML element with jQuery you can use `.attr();`

so `$('html').attr('someAttribute');` will give you the value of `someAttribute` of the element `html`

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

#### Additionally:

there is a jQuery plugin here: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/getAttributes

that allows you to get all attributes from an HTML element

Comment: The getAttributes() project is a bit old now (Feb 2009).

Answer (score 4):

I found other alternative simple way using plain javascript:

```js
const htmlElement = document.querySelector(':root')
console.log(htmlElement)
```