# Get DocType of an HTML as string with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I know that I can access to doctype object via `document.doctype` or `document.childNodes[0]` but my problem is getting doctype as a string. I can do this in chrome and safari by calling `document.doctype` which returns `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`. However in Firefox, calling `document.doctype` returns DocumentType object.

Is there a way to get the doctype string in all browsers as in chrome and safari?

Thanks!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

In all compliant browsers (including Chrome/Safari), [`document.doctype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.doctype) also returns a [`DocumentType`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-412266927) object. The following code can be used to generate a valid DOCTYPE string.

```
var node = document.doctype;
var html = "<!DOCTYPE "
         + node.name
         + (node.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + node.publicId + '"' : '')
         + (!node.publicId && node.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '') 
         + (node.systemId ? ' "' + node.systemId + '"' : '')
         + '>';
```

This method returns the correct string for [valid (HTML5) doctypes](http://www.totalvalidator.com/support/doctypes.html), eg:

- `<!DOCTYPE html>`
- `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">`
- `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">`

Explanation of the code:

```
node.name      # Holds the name of the root element, eg: HTML / html
node.publicId  # If this property is present, then it's a public document type.
               #>Prefix PUBLIC
!node.publicId && node.systemId
               # If there's no publicId, but a systemId, prefix SYSTEM
node.systemId  # Append this if present
```

Comment: Worth noting documents with no DOCTYPE have a `document.doctype === null`.

Answer (score 57):

You can also use this one liner to get the current doctype. This will work in [any modern browser and IE 9 and higher](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XMLSerializer#Browser_compatibility).

```
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.doctype);
```

Comment: This will be added `xmlns` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

```
function get_doctype()
{
    var doctype = 
    '<!DOCTYPE ' + 
    document.doctype.name +
    (document.doctype.publicId?' PUBLIC "' +  document.doctype.publicId + '"':'') +
    (document.doctype.systemId?' "' + document.doctype.systemId + '"':'') + '>';
    return doctype;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what are you looking for ?

```
alert(document.doctype.publicId);
```

Comment: That returns only `-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN`. I need whole DOCTYPE

Comment: Maybe you need to do --- var doc = '<!DOCTYPE '+document.doctype.name+' PUBLIC "'+document.doctype.publicId+'" "'+document.doctype.systemId+'">';

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate `DocumentType.name`, `.publicId` and `.systemId`. Something like:

```
'<!DOCTYPE '+ 
  DocumentType.name+' PUBLIC "'+ //maybe you should check for publicId first
  DocumentType.publicId+'" "'+
  DocumentType.systemId+'">'
```

Comment: I'm guessing this doesn't support HTML5?

Comment: @Kendall: it does, but isn't very informative for html5 afaik.

Comment: I mean, it should print `<!DOCTYPE html>`, but for this page (which uses HTML5 doctype), I get `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "" "">`.