# How to check if a DOM Node is the node representing the doctype declaration?

Tags: html, dom, internet-explorer-8, doctype

So let's say (in IE8) that we have a `document`.

Now normally we can assume that `document.childNodes[0]` is the doctype. So

`var doctype = document.childNodes[0]`

Now how do we *confirm* rather then assume it is the doctype?

```
doctype.nodeType === Node.COMMENT_NODE;
doctype.tagName === "!"; // same as a comment
doctype.data.indexOf("DOCTYPE ") > -1; // same as any comment containing the word DOCTYPE.
doctype === document.doctype; // false, document.doctype is undefined in IE8
```

Apart from assumptions, how am I supposed to know whether a given node is a doctype?

For those of you unfamiliar with DOM4 take a look at [`DocumentType`](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#interface-documenttype)

The [DOM-shim](https://github.com/Raynos/DOM-shim/blob/master/src/interfaces/Document/getter/doctype.js#L3) get's `document.doctype` in IE8 by just returning `document.childNodes[0]`

Comment: Is the doctype really part of the DOM? I was under the impression that it isn't. I can be wrong though.

Comment: In Chrome/Mac, the node type is `Node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE`.

Comment: @Pekka Yes it is. Just check what `document.childNodes[0]` is on this page.

Comment: @Pekka `document.doctype` aswell.

Comment: @Inerdia my comedy title :( why did you ruin it and turn it into a sensible one.

Comment: It seems to be in IE7 and IE8

Comment: I fear the answer is always `false`. The node at document.childNodes[0] in IE8 is *not* the doctype node, it's more like a placeholder (comment) node in lieu of where the doctype node ought to be. JS apart, there's really no need for IE to retain a real doctype node once the quirks vs standards flag's been set, and I suspect it simply didn't.

Comment: @Alohci I see. IE8 does not have any concept of document node, it just  has comment at `document.childNodes[0]`. This is a sad day. IE8 did another thing wrong :(

Comment: Maybe `doctype.data.indexOf("<!DOCTYPE html") !== -1 && doctype.data.indexOf(">") !== -1`?

Comment: @mc10 that sounds like just as bad of assumption as `document.childNodes[0]`. However I'd be interesting to see whether a DOCTYPE can have any other position in the DOM

Comment: @Raynos - It might not be a smart thing to do, but comments that precede the doctype in the markup will take node positions that precede the doctype in the DOM. So it might not be at `childNodes[0]`. I believe that only comment nodes, (and anything treated by the parser as a comment node, e.g. an xml declaration)  can precede the doctype. Anything else and the browser parser will ignore the doctype markup.

Comment: If you know the form of your doctype, you could do something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088972/get-doctype-of-an-html-as-string-with-javascript/6089056#6089056

Comment: mc10's idea is probably correct. I don't know about ie8 but Python dom nodes have 2 attributes "publicId" and "systemId" that don't seem to appear in normal nodes.

Comment: @AndrewStone `publicId`, `name` & `systemId` do not work in IE8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that in IE7 and IE8 the `.innerHTML` property for comments is always the full `"<!--comment here-->"` and for the doctype node, it is `""`. Even for empty comments, the `.innerHTML` is `"<!---->"`

So based on this I created:

```
function isDocType(node) {
    return node && (
    node.nodeType === 10 || (node.nodeType === 8 && "innerHTML" in node && node.innerHTML === ""));
}
```

With the test page:

```
<!-- comment1 -->
<!-- comment2 -->
<!---->
<!-- -->
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html> -->
```

Running doctype and the comments through `isDocType` gives:

```
LOG: true 
LOG: false 
LOG: false 
LOG: false 
LOG: false 
LOG: false
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/AEYt4/

Comment: Wow. How did you find this out?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine I did `console.dir` of both, then compared them side by side in excel

Answer (score 0):

IE8 says no. :(

Seriously though, apart from hacks and assumptions there is no clean way.

As suggested in the comments you can assume comments are not doctype like

`doctype.data.indexOf("<!DOCTYPE html") !== -1 && doctype.data.indexOf(">") !== -1`

Or make assumptions about the DOM structure

> I believe that only comment nodes, (and anything treated by the parser as a comment node, e.g. an xml declaration) can precede the doctype

So you can just loop over the comment nodes in `document.childNodes` until you find one that matches the above regexp.

Comment: No. You shouldn't be looking for comment nodes. You should be looking specifically for `node.nodeType === 10` (`DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE`). Any other type is an incorrect implementation and best left ignored.

Comment: I believe any browser that actually has `nodeType === 10` for the doctype node has `document.doctype`