# Get the whole document's html with JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know it's already discussed here, but there were no solution to get the whole document (including doctype).

`$(document).html();` returns `null`...

Comment: Why does nobody read the question (**"including doctype"**) before answering ?

Comment: Because everybody wants to be the first to get points ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will get you all the HTML:

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

Unfortunately it does not return the doctype. But you can use `document.doctype` to get it and glue the two together.

Comment: You were the first mentioning `document.doctype`. So I accepted your answer. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 8):

You can do

```
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document);
```

for all browsers newer than IE 9

Answer (score 4):

try this.

```
$("html").html()
```

document is a variable it dose not represent the html tag.

**EDIT**

To get the doctype one could use

```
document.doctype
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question : this doesn't include the doctype.

Answer (score 4):

This is a function which has support in IE6+, it does't use `outerHTML` for even more support, it adds the doctype and uses a few tricks to get the `html` tag and its attributes. In order to receive a string with the doctype, and doesn't use `outerHTML` so it supports every browser. It uses a few tricks to get the `html` tag. Add this code:

```
document.fullHTML = function () {
    var r = document.documentElement.innerHTML, t = document.documentElement.attributes, i = 0, l = '',
        d = '<!DOCTYPE ' + document.doctype.name + (document.doctype.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + document.doctype.publicId + '"' : '') + (!document.doctype.publicId && document.doctype.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '') + (document.doctype.systemId ? ' "' + document.doctype.systemId + '"' : '') + '>';
    for (; i < t.length; i += 1) l += ' ' + t[i].name + '="' + t[i].value + '"';
    return d+'\n<html' + l + '>' + r + '</html>';
}
```

Now, you can run this function:

```
console.log(document.fullHTML());
```

This will return the HTML and doctype.

I ran this on [example.com](http://example.com), [here are the results](http://pastebin.com/QJfg4c0h)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

will return you all document markup as string

to get the whole doctype read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088972/get-doctype-of-an-html-as-string-with-javascript)

Comment: Close but no cookie:) It doesn't return the doctype.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about getting the complete doc.but what you can do is,you can get the content of html tag seprately and doctype seprately.

`$('html').html() for content` and [document.doctype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.doctype) for getting the doctype

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct access to the whole document (including the doctype), but this works :

```
$.get(document.location, function(html) {
    // use html (which is the complete source code, including the doctype)
});
```

Comment: i think it is more efficient to use the document already opened instead of "reloading" it by firing an ajax request...

Comment: @dtrunk yes but nothing else really gives the whole source code including the exact doctype typed (`document.doctype` is the nearest thing you have but not the exact one).

Comment: Additionally it can be noted that this usually won't fire a request as the document is cached.

Answer (score 0):

> I have done it on browser's console

**document.documentElement;**

Comment: Consider adding more details and the usage of formatted codes

Comment: Note that `document.documentElement` returns a **Object** where `document.documentElement.outerHTML` returns a **String**