# Assigning output of external Javascript src to avoid script hang out

Tags: php, javascript

I have two websites: `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`.

The script on `domain1.com/external.php` is:

```
<?php
echo <<<ots
<!--
document.write('Hello World!');
//-->
ots;
?>
```

I want to execute this `external.php` script on `domain2.com`, so I use:

```
<script src="http://domain1.com/external.php"></script>
```

---

The problem is - the Javascript often hangs out, so I wanted to include the `< script..`  right below the `< /body>`. However, I must print the `Hello World!` text in a specific place on the page (ie. right after the `</head>`).

Question - can I include the `< script..` right below the `< /body>` to assign the output somehow and then put this variable on the page after the script executes?

Or any other similar solution? I cannot use JQuery.

Comment: Use `document.getElementById('idOfTarget').innerHTML='Hello World!';` [See also this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17531159/1935077).

Comment: external.php I provided above is just an example - it is much more complicated than just printing the 'Hello World!' text. I MUST use the external.php script from domain1.com..

Comment: Why do you need the `echo` part?

Comment: `document.write` will _destroy_ the page's content if the document is already closed. You should consider Petr's suggestion.

Comment: @PetrR. You should post as answer.

Doesn't matter what the script do. Run the script, save the string in a variable, and print it as Petr R. said. Is easy and you should have no problems.

Comment: I need `echo` part because external.php is a PHP script. In general, it connects to MySQL database, takes the results (some texts) and prints it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML)** to replace the content of one element on the page:

```
document.getElementById('idOfTarget').innerHTML='Hello World!';
```

Please note that you can modify the element only after it's created, so put the script before `</body>` if possible or use **[`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload)** event:

```
window.onload=function(){
     document.getElementById('idOfTarget').innerHTML='Hello World!';
};
```

*See also [this mine earlier answer to see how to replace an element by the classname or the tagname.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17531159/1935077)*

---

If you need to use PHP in your script, then you still can do that:

```
window.onload=function(){
     document.getElementById('idOfTarget').innerHTML='<?php
          echo "Hello World!";
     ?>';
};
```

*Please note that if you want to update a lot of elements, you may want to use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)/[JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON).*

Comment: Thanks, but what about the external.php Javascript script part? (you may see my additional comment above).

Comment: @Tom - You still can use PHP without any limitations, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok, I think I get an idea and hopefully I can manage to implement it :

Comment: @Tom - Good luck! Feel free to ask for any clarification, if needed. Also, please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/224130) if this helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can but you have to use in your `external.php` file

```
header('Content-type: text/javascript');
```

So it's possible to use it like

```
<script src="http://domain1.com/external.php"></script>
```