# valueOf() gives different values in script and F12 console (Chrome and IE11 only)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, dom

Here is a [simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Phar/1/):

```
alert(document.doctype.valueOf())
```

It produces `[object DocumentType]`, as expected.

However, when I hit F12 and just type `document.doctype.valueOf()` in the JavaScript console (Chrome, IE11), I see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Why is the discrepancy, and what property (if any) does it actually show in the console mode?

**[UPDATE]** When I mentioned that `document.doctype.outerHTML` used to work until IE11 in the comments to @BlueSkies's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19871234/1768303), I was not quite correct. In my case, I host a WinForms version of [IE `WebBrowser` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in a C# app. I've just discovered it works like this, in IE11 too:

```
dynamic domDocument = webBrowser.Document.DomDocument;

// this shows '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "" "">'
string doctype = domDocument.doctype.outerHTML;
MessageBox.Show(doctype); 

// this shows 'undefined'
domDocument.parentWindow.execScript("alert(document.doctype.outerHTML)");
```

Apparently, it works from outside, but not from inside the page. Interesting, but unreliable. I guess I should not use `document.doctype.outerHTML` even in this IE-based app.

Comment: The console shows `name`, `publicId` and `systemId` properties of `document.doctype`.

Comment: @Teemu, so the console gives a kind of special treatment to `document.doctype` object?

Comment: In a way, yes. But the same is done with the most of the logged objects. `document.doctype` is just a regular host object provided by a browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.valueOf()` returns neither output. What it returns is the actual node.

So the `alert()` is giving you the `.toString()` of the node, and the Chrome/IE consoles have simply decided to serialize the node to HTML.

```
document.doctype.valueOf() === document.doctype; // true
```

---

Here's a little experiment...

```
document.doctype.toString = function() { return "foobar"; }

alert(document.doctype.valueOf());  // shows "foobar"
```

Comment: Hmm.. can you serialize this node to HTML with JavaScript, **just the same way the console does**, without resorting to a technique like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10162353 ? That's my point about the difference.

Comment: @Noseratio: No, to my knowledge there's no built in method to do this. The console probably uses some code similar to that answer. I don't believe `.inner/outerHTML` can give you the markup. The console is an addon. There's no specification that defines its behavior.

Comment: For IE, `document.doctype.outerHTML` used to work until IE11. Also, while `.valueOf()` indeed returns the actual node in this case, **that does not apply to every object**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ftx8swz5(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: For Objects that are a box for a primitive value, it returns the primitive. Otherwise it returns the object. And don't forget that DOM nodes are host objects. They're not required to obey all the rules of native ECMAScript objects. Maybe the DOM spec or HTML5 spec defines `.valueOf()` for DOM nodes. Not sure.

Comment: Thanks, I'll let the question to hang on for a little longer before accepting your answer, just to see if there any other ideas.