# How to get Html code after javascript has modified it?

Tags: javascript, python, html, dom

I want to get the HTML code of a webpage after it has been modified (similar to one that we see in inspect element tab of a browser) and I want to do it programatically (if possible using python or any other programming language). Can someone suggest how I might be able to proceed with this? I know its possible since browsers are able to do it.

Comment: javascript: `.innerHTML`, jQuery:  `.html()`

Comment: In javascript you could do something like: 'getElementyByTagName('HTML'), right before the block code ends of the event fired, which made the DOM manipulation :); as Ashish Kumar mentioned above, .innerHTML gives you the HTML inside the element, if you need only text, you could do .text / .value on the element in question

Comment: What is your usecase? The current answers asume a browser. If you are scraping you should use something like selenium.

Comment: I am hitting an API which gives me a HTML(with javascript). I want to parse the html(after javascript modification) and return some specific tag-fields.

Comment: With what are you doing the requests to the api?

Comment: The request are simple POST api calls through urllib.request module of python3.

Answer (score 1):

As the server has no access to client window after client-side changes, you have to use client side languages.

In jquery:

```
var fullCode= "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>";
```

if you want also to include the Doctype:

```
var node = document.doctype;
var fullCode = "<!DOCTYPE "
         + node.name
         + (node.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + node.publicId + '"' : '')
         + (!node.publicId && node.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '') 
         + (node.systemId ? ' "' + node.systemId + '"' : '')
         + '>';
fullcode += "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>";
```

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088972/get-doctype-of-an-html-as-string-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery you can achieve this by the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var html = "<html>"+$('html').html()+"</html>";
});
```

Comment: This doesn't really make it so that the page content is refreshed when a function is fired.