# javascript save document to .html

Tags: javascript, dom, download, save, google-chrome-console

I have `document` and I want everything inside the <html> (which is enough to render the page)
including or not including the (`<html>` or `DOCTYPE`)

```js
document.save("name.html")
```

or

```js
saveDocument(document, "name.html")
```

or document inside <iframe>: here innerDocument is a document

```js
var iframe = document.querySelector("#idOfIframe")
var innerDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document
saveDocument(innerDocument, "name.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
downloadString(documentToString(document), document.title + '.html')
function downloadString(string, filename, type) {
    var file = new Blob([string], { type: type })
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) // IE10+
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, filename)
    else { // Others
        var a = document.createElement("a"),
            url = URL.createObjectURL(file)
        a.href = url
        a.download = filename
        document.body.appendChild(a)
        a.click()
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.body.removeChild(a)
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
        }, 0)
    }
}
function documentToString(document) {
    let doctype = getDoctype(document)
    return (doctype !== false ? doctype + '\n' : '') + document.documentElement.outerHTML
}
function getDoctype(document) {
    var node = document.doctype
    if (node) {
        var html = "<!DOCTYPE "
            + node.name
            + (node.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + node.publicId + '"' : '')
            + (!node.publicId && node.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '')
            + (node.systemId ? ' "' + node.systemId + '"' : '')
            + '>'
    }
    if (html) {
        return html
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

if you need to get document inside an iframe:

```js
var iframe = document.querySelector("#idOfIframe")
var innerDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document
downloadString(documentToString(innerDocument), innerDocument.title + '.html')
```

if you want to use `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document)` instead of `document.documentElement.outerHTML`
read the comments here to see the differences: [How to get the entire document HTML as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817218/how-to-get-the-entire-document-html-as-a-string/35917295#35917295)

```js
downloadString(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document), document.title + '.html')
```

sources:
[How to get the entire document HTML as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817218/how-to-get-the-entire-document-html-as-a-string)
[Get DocType of an HTML as string with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088972/get-doctype-of-an-html-as-string-with-javascript)
[JavaScript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file/29576427)