# Any cross browser issues with document.documentElement

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Any cross browser issues if I use document.documentElement ?

Target browsers are

- Firefox
- Internet Explorer
- Opera
- Safari
- Android
- iOS
- BlackBerry

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Please do a google search before asking: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.documentElement

Comment: I did that and already read the url you provided. Thats why I am asking... In the MDN url you provided, on top its mentioned as Gekco DOM ref, does that mean its only for Gecko based browsers or is it applicable to Webkit as well as Trident based browsers?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should have no problems: 
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html

Anyway here you have a test page:
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/document.html#documentElement

Answer (score 4):

[Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html) says

`document.documentElement.clientWidth/Height`

- **Meaning**: Viewport dimensions Measured in CSS pixels
- **Browser errors**: None

http://duckduckgo.com/?q=!%20document.documentElement%20site%3Aquirksmode.org