# how to get the font size of html tag

Tags: javascript, css, html, fonts, font-size

I'm trying to get the root font size of an html file.
below is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>el query</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
            font-size: 10px;
        }
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="testDivWrapper">
        <div id="testDiv">
            <div class="child">
                <div class="target"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but when i try to get any font information, I am not able to get any font information. I have tried using the following js:

```
document.documentElement.style.fontSize
document.body.style.fontSize
```

but i come up with empty strings. any ideas?

Comment: `window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('font-size');`

Comment: While the duplicate explains how to get the font size from an element, it's not addressing the actual `<html>` tag, which is relevant to know the value from which the `rem` values are calculated from. [This can be achieved by using the `document.documentElement`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4196971/1218980)

Comment: regarding `rem` apparently not a duplicate

Comment: in `jquery` you do `$('html').css('font-size')`, I can't quickly google pure js solution. proposed answers are apparently incorrect as they return *body* font-size

Comment: I see it now:
`window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize;`
or
`window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('html')).getPropertyValue('font-size');`

Answer (score 17):

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('font-size');
```