# How to take html element without text?

Tags: javascript

Edit:

sorry for bad explanation so i have:

```
 var x = $("span", this).get( 0 );
 var y = x.outerHTML
```

and it give me:
 `<span>'some text'</span>` but i want just only tag `<span></span>` with all atributes. My question is how to get it?;p

thanks for any help!

Comment: Your question is unclear, as far as I understand it I would just say "delete the 'a'" but you obviously want something else

Comment: `<span>&nbsp;</span>` should work

Comment: why wouldn't `<span></span>` work?

Comment: See here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/22873490/1944351

Comment: You are right @VelimirTchatchevsky. Just thought Puki might be looking for something else.

Comment: Very unclear, Please provide more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code:
var x = $("span", this).get( 0 ); <-- you have parent (even TAG name) and taking first child
var y = x.outerHTML <-- here you're trying to get parent (you eant - TAG name) :%

So, if you know var x = $("span"... <---- this string - you can easily create a string you want

```
var tag = "span";
var x = $(tag, this).get( 0 );
var y = x.outerHTML;
// the most dumbest way
var result = '<'+tag+'>'+'<'+tag+'/>';
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method does not preserve attributes as required in the question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cyz02qqy/1/ 
What about this?

$(SOME_SELECTOR).html('').prop("outerHTML")

Answer (score 0):

`cloneNode()` by default does not copy the element content, so you can use it:

```
var x = $("span", this).get( 0 );
var y = x.cloneNode();
var z = x.outerHTML;
```

In your function of fiddle it would be something like that:

```
var x = tur.cloneNode();
console.log(x.outerHTML);
```