# How to get the `html` element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the `html` element in Javascript.  I can now use `document.body.parentNode` or `document.getElementsByTagName("html")`.  But I think there should be a simple, "right" way to do it.

So, what's the right way to get the `html` element in Javascript?

I tried to use search engines, but I don't know how to tell them the `html` tag is different from any other HTML tag, so it yielded no result I wanted.

Comment: Why you need to get th html tag?

Comment: use <html id='myHtml'> and document.getElementById('myHtml')

Comment: `document.querySelector(':root')`

Comment: @WaelAbbas It's because I was thinking about quine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
document.documentElement
```

which points to the document's root `html` node.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement

Answer (score 1):

Chek this answer 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22873490/3134112

reference:

 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.documentElement.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say `document.getElementsByTagName`, `querySelector` etc. are all "right ways" to get reference to html tag, it doesn't get simpler than that.