# changing html element background image js

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

i have searched google and on here but i cant exactly find a correct answer to my problem i used this code:

```
html {
   background: url('../resources/imgs/bgs/mainbg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

that i got from the internet to set a background image that is always in the center and fits perfecly in the browser and it works great but i ran into a problem. i need to change the background image on a button click but i dont know how to target the html tag is it even possible? many thanks :)

my question was flagged as a duplicate but my problrm is not just getting the style of the html elememnt but changing it the same as the code snippet using only pure javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the <html> tag HTML with JavaScript / jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196971/how-to-get-the-html-tag-html-with-javascript-jquery)

Comment: "javascript get html element" typed into Google could have led you to that duplicate directly.

Comment: Please include code that you have tried, it gives us more context as to what you are trying to achieve and makes it easier to pinpoint where you might be going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set both `backgroundImage` and `backgroundSize` property. Try the following:

```js
document.querySelector('#btnSetImage').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var html = document.querySelector('html');
  html.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.noodleman.co.uk/images/source/google_merchant_bulk_category_assign/google.jpg')";
  html.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btnSetImage">Set Background Image</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('img_tree.png')";
```

Comment: Too fast answer, I fixed it :)

Comment: that didnt work the new image is just placed in the corner and not the whole screen

Comment: @kriskotooBG so maybe try: `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.background = "url('img.png') no-repeat center center fixed";`

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you could do the following

```
$('html').on('click', function(){
    $('html').css({
      "background": "url('https://picsum.photos/1200/3300/?blur') no-repeat center center fixed",
      "background-size": "cover"
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry but i didnt ask for a jquery solution

Comment: then you can just add two different styles with javascript ----document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.background = "url('https://picsum.photos/1200/3300/?blur') no-repeat center center fixed";
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.backgroundSize = 'cover';

Answer (score 0):

You can access the html element directly with `documentElement`:

```js
/*Just change the image source with javascript*/
document.querySelector('#changeImage').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.documentElement.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://www.fillmurray.com/400/400")';
});
```

```css
/*Base settings in CSS*/

html {
  background: url('https://www.fillmurray.com/g/400/400') no-repeat center center fixed;
  /*This Would be a greyscale image*/
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div style="color:#FFF;">Bill Murray!</div>
<!-- Just Some Content -->
<button id="changeImage">ChangeImage</button>
```