# Javascript display an html pge from a variable containing code

Tags: javascript, html

In my project i have a javascript file that contain a variable like this one:

```
var htmlcode = "<html><body><h1>My First Web Page</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>"
```

i would to know if in javascript exist a command for render my htmlcode variable ina real html page, i think to use a button for open that page.

So many thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending HTML string to the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327056/appending-html-string-to-the-dom)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can use  `$('html')` to select the HTML tag, and change its content using `$('html').html("some new content")`:

```js
$("#changeHTML").click(function() {
  $('html').html("<body><div style='color:red;'>New sample text</div></body>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  Sample text
  <button id="changeHTML">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Using plain Javascript, you can use `document.documentElement` to select the document's HTML tag ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196971/how-to-get-the-html-tag-html-with-javascript-jquery)), and changing this variable's `innerHTML` should do the trick.