# How to get the full code of an html document in javascript including dynamically injected html or scripts or css?

Tags: javascript

I have search all over internet if  get the full code of an html document in javascript including dynamically injected html or scripts or css
and cannot find any clue.

So is it possible ? If yes any code snippet ?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but you can just save a webpage from the browser.  On Chrome I am able to download the css, js, and assets as well as the HTML document.

Comment: *"dynamically injected html"* - Do you mean, for example, changes to the DOM performed by the JavaScript code being executed on that page?  If so then the search term you're looking for is probably "headless browser".

Comment: Any reason you can't just use `document.querySelector('html').innerHTML`?

Comment: Checkout this resource. It shows details of different ways of achieving your results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196971/how-to-get-the-html-tag-html-with-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

would give you the entire HTML of the current DOM state, including changes made by JavaScript. Not sure what you mean by "including CSS".

If you use it, don't forget to add

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

at the top