# compatibility mode issue in IE 9

Tags: html, web-applications, compatibility

This Question is follow up to the question already there on stackoverflow [What is the purpose of the HTML "no-js" class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724515/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-html-no-js-class) When i have this code in my file in the compatibility mode even though i have

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

which should instruct the browser to render in latest version even in the compatibility mode,But its not able to do that and browser switches to IE7 mode and my application wont work fine. So IS there any conflict and what should i do to fix this?