# what is the meaning of no-js class in html5

Tags: html, css

i seen lot of website have specific code for ie6, ie7,ie8.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

and i seem html have specific class like this

```
<html class=" js no-flexbox flexbox-legacy canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths">
```

any one just tell what is the use this codes

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724515/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-html-no-js-class

Answer (score 10):

This is instruction for Moderniz. If JavaScript in your browser is enabled, Modernizr changes `no-js` to `js` class, so you can define CSS styles for JavaScript-enabled browsers and for JavaScript-disabled browsers

Answer (score 7):

It's put there so that if there ***IS*** Javascript support, then you can use JS to remove the `no-js` class.

You use the `no-js` class to style CSS for your webpage if you normally require JS for your site to function properly.
This provides a degraded but functional format, if you want to serve enough HTML and enough forms to make the page work without JS, but then hide the ghetto-version and replace it with the shiny and fancy stuff, later.

Answer (score 3):

`<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->` is Microsoft's [conditional comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx).

So for IE version < 7 (`[if lt IE 7]`), `<html lang="en" class="no-js ie6">` is used;

For IE version 7 (`[if IE 7]`), `<html lang="en" class="no-js ie7">` is used;

and so on.

Finally, for IE version > 9(`[if gt IE 9]`), `<html lang="en" class="no-js">` is used.

And since it is a Microsoft specific comment, all non-IE browsers will treat it as normal comment, so only `<html lang="en" class="no-js">` (the only un-commented part) is used.