# Javascript accessing new window's element

Tags: javascript, dom, window, html-table

I am creating a new html tab that among other things will show a table. I leave the table empty because i will fill it after with a Dynatable JS (filles a table with a given JSON). Code:

```
    var html_ticket = '<!doctype html>' +
'<html dir="ltr" lang="en" class="no-js">' +
'<head> ' +

(...)

'</head> ' +
'<body> ' +

(...)

'           <table id="ticket_table" > ' +
'               <thead> ' +
'                       <th>Timestamp</th> ' +
'                       <th>Amount</th> ' +
'               </thead> ' +
'               <tbody> ' +
'               </tbody> ' +
'           </table> ' +

(...)

'</body> ' +
'</html> ';
```

Then i open that html code in a new tab like this:

```
var newWindow = window.open();
newWindow.document.write(html_ticket);
```

Ok the next thing i need to do is to fill the table with the info. I am using a JS that fills the table with a given JSON. I've used it several times and worked perfect, but this time the table is not filled, keeps empty. Code:

```
var table = newWindow.document.getElementById('ticket_table');

table.dynatable({

              features: {
                paginate: true,
                sort: false,
                pushState: false,
                search: false,
                recordCount: true,
                perPageSelect: false
              },
              dataset: {
                records: getInfoJSON()
              }
});
```

I am suspecting that I am not accessing the new windows's element properly.. could this be the issue?

Comment: I added a newWindow.onload function just in case it tried to fill the table before the site was loaded. no changes...

Comment: what is the use of `class="no-js"`?

Comment: "When Modernizr runs, it removes the "no-js" class and replaces it with "js". This is a way to know in your CSS whether or not Javascript support is enabled." font: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724515/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-html-no-js-class

Comment: I removed it and no changes at all

Comment: You can try this, write a JS function(say abc)in newwindow's document html, that takes a param, and binds to table. In calling page use `newWindow.document.ABC(param)` .

Comment: Any errors on the console?

Comment: No. I changed the approach. I created an .html file which loaded the JS script on document.ready. This way worked for me...

Comment: Well, then it seems to me that this question is moot.