# javascript usage in html tag

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

what does this mean? why are they applying it only to IE(internet explorer)?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724515/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-html-no-js-class

Comment: This query was introuced by Microsoft, for cross browsing. Fortunatly it wasn't taken by W3C. So it does exists only in IE.

Comment: Sorry, I think I actually misread your question. Are you talking about the comment conditionals or the `class="no-js"` attribute?

Comment: i am asking what does those comment conditionals mean?

Answer (score 0):

There is no JavaScript there.

Those are conditional comments: a hack supported by old versions of IE that misapplied HTML's comment syntax to do browser detection.

Further reading:

- [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment)
- [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)
- [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx)