# Prevent to load a page with js disabled

Tags: javascript, html, loading

It's possible to disable an entire page html if the js is disabled on the browser of the user?
EDIT:
Thank you all for the answers and comments! However, what I mean is: I want that the page is replaced with something else, like an image, in that case.

Comment: not exactly a duplicate, but this thread will answer your question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724515/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-html-no-js-class

Comment: Do you mean disable a link to page?  Or what do you mean exactly by "disable"?

Comment: You'll probably need the page to render the replaced content by default with a JS call that actually swaps that out for the real content.  If JS is disabled, the call won't go through and the failover content is shown, but if the JS call is successful then it would show the proper content

Comment: I edited the question. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @Yosvel's answer is what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `noscript` tag defines an alternate content for users that have disabled scripts in their browser or have a browser that doesn't support script.

You can do something like this in your html body to display whatever image you want to show:

```
<noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper {display:none;}
    </style>
    <div>
        <img src="src/to/your/image.png" alt="You don't have javascript enabled">
    </div>
</noscript>
```

The css inside the `noscript` tag will hide the html content inside the `wrapper` class.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of. Somewhere somehow you need to tell the browser to prevent the action/event linked to it, eg returning false, which is a task for javascript. I can come up with two alternatives:

**Make all anchors dummies and correct them when JS is turned on:**

```
<a href="#" data-href="/actual-url">foo</a> 
$('a').each(function(){ this.href = $(this).data("href");} // * jQuery for simplicity
```

**Put an layer on top of the anchor, which you can remove with JS.**

```
.BlockedAnchor a{ position: relative; }
.BlockedAnchor a:before{ 
    position: absolute; 
    display: block;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
$('body'removeClass("BlockedAnchor");
```