# slicknav not displaying, but is recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, slicknav

I have been trying to incorporate a slicknav menu into my project for school, I'm not entirely new to coding and i believe my mistake is quite simple but after 3 hours of racking my brain i cant seem to find the solution to my problem, some help, insight or tips on how to fix it or perhaps improve my code would be greatly appreciated. (by the way i already have a functioning drop down menu for some things but I'd like to have a slicknav for mobile screens

```
html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Shape up!</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
<!--^^^TITLE LOGO^^^-->
<link href="styles/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="styles/main_rwd.css" rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css">
<link href="styles/slicknav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
<!--    <script href="js/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
<script>
   $(function(){
    $('#nav_menu').slicknav();
});
</script>
</head>
<header>
<img src="images/shape_up_logo.png" alt="Shape up logo">
<!--^^^SITE LOGO^^^--> 
<h1 id="logo"><a href="/index.html">Shape Up!</a></h1>
<h3>Find the best fit for you!</h3>
</header>

<body>
<main>
 <nav id="nav_menu">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="strength/index.html">Strength Training</a>
             <ul>
                 <li></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="cardio/index.html">Cardio Exercises</a></li>
         <li><a href="stress/index.html">Stress Relief</a>
            <ul>
                 <li><a href="stress/index.html">What is Stress?</a></li>
                 <li><a href="stress/tips.html">5 Helpful Tips</a></li>
                 <li><a href="stress/meditate.html">Meditation</a></li>
                 <li><a href="stress/vipassana.html">Vipassana</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="diet/index.html">Healthy Diets</a>
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="diet/index.html">Why a Healthy Diet?</a></li>
                 <li><a href="diet/meals.html">Plan Your Meals</a></li>
                 <li><a href="diet/calories.html">Count Your Calories</a> 
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="diet/bmi.html">Calculate Your BMI</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
```

And the next portion is the css code regarding the slicknav

```
slicknav_menu {
display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
body {
    box-shadow: none;
    font-size: 90%;
}
}
/*
TABLET SIZE^^^
.slicknav_menu {
display:none;
}
*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

#nav_menu {
    display: none; 
}
.js .slicknav_menu {
    display: block;
}

}
```

I have commented some stuff out for trouble shooting reasons
any help would be appreciated as i probably missed a simple thing anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your style rule:

```
.js .slicknav_menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Is looking for a class, `.js` that does not exist in your document. The typical use of the `.js` class is to dynamically add it to the `<body>` tag with javascript so you can manage your site differently for users with and without javascript enabled.

Try removing `.js` from your style rule, or dynamically add `.js` with something like `$(document).ready(function(){$(body).addClass('js')})`

Comment: tried removing the .js tag but no luck,  also where might it add the dynamic .js adder?

Comment: would it be something like this?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
      <script>
    $(function(){
        $(document).ready(function(){$(body).addClass('js')})
  $('#nav_menu').slicknav();
 });
        </script>

Comment: @TheManBand91 yes, though you do have an extra <script> in there after the first <script>. That should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I FINALLY DID IT! 
however I'm sorry to say i don't exactly know how i did it. I deleted some things here and there, i don't quite remember what i did exactly delete. though i will provide code for anybody that encounters a similar problem, i know have to work on getting it where i need it to be.
Main script section:

```
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script>
   <script src="js/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
        <script>
   $(function(){
   $(document).ready(function(){$(body).addClass('js')}) 
   $('#nav_menu').slicknav();
   });
   </script>
```

and the css file:

```
 .slicknav_menu {
 display:none;
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
 body {
    box-shadow: none;
    font-size: 90%;
}
}



 @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

 #nav_menu {
    display: none; 
 }
 .slicknav_menu {
    display: block;
    position: inherit;
 }

 }
```

Comment: if you're referring to me, not a man, and you're welcome :) -- I do think that perhaps you could do without the `.js` logic altogether, though it might be: a) within the scope of your project or b) if it ain't broke don't fix it

Comment: Here's a related SO that provides some more info about `.js` and `.no-js` classes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724515/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-html-no-js-class