# Hide page until it's all loaded

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make the browser wait to display the page until it's fully loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435015/how-can-i-make-the-browser-wait-to-display-the-page-until-its-fully-loaded)

I've got a simple website and I'd like to hold it's opening for X ms before I'm sure it's all loaded (like images for example).
Is there a way to make this to the whole page at once?

I already have some fades to open the various div's of the site but I'd like that fade to only occur after the page has waited for those X ms set by the "loading".

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## jQuery

```
<body>
<div id="msg" style="font-size:largest;">
<!-- you can set whatever style you want on this -->
Loading, please wait...
</div>
<div id="body" style="display:none;">
<!-- everything else -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#body').show();
    $('#msg').hide();
});
</script>
</body>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#container').css('opacity', 0);
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#container').css('opacity', 1);
});
</script>
```

or

Immediately following your  tag add something like this...

```
 <style> body  {opacity:0;}</style>
```

And for the very first thing in your  add something like...

```
 <script>
  window.onload = function() {setTimeout(function(){document.body.style.opacity="100";},500);};
 </script>
```

All these answers are from **[How can I make the browser wait to display the page until it's fully loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435015/how-can-i-make-the-browser-wait-to-display-the-page-until-its-fully-loaded)**

Comment: Thank you very much. The last option did the job easily. I was having a stupid problem because, before all the fades start, I was able to have a glimpse on some div's and then they would all hide and animate the fade. Now everything it's clean until they start fading.

Comment: No problem sometimes it can also occur when people call JavaScript files at the bottom of the page for speed etc

Answer (score 1):

if you use jQuery, just create a div with "please wait" and an other one with all your content but with style="display:none", su put this code to swap then when its ready.

```
jQuery.ready(function(){jQuery('#pleasewait').fadeOut('slow'); jQuery('#content').fadeIn('slow');})
```