# How to prevent gradually showing a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

My site loads images very slowly. Some text appears, then some tables, then some images... and then - body background image.
How can I force that nothing should be displayed till whole the page is ready ?

Comment: Hopefully that gets you the right direction, I agree with the top answer over there.  Some sort of processing should show so people don't think you have a poor server.

Comment: Yes, I saw your link, and it seems I'll tray with small gif image (loader) and jQuery onload() to change css of images. Maybe you should design your comment as answer. Thanks again.

Comment: There you go.  Great idea, onload will work as well.

Comment: Why was this migrated here - its just as offtopic on SO :)

Answer (score 4):

You could add a class at the `body` which has `display:none` and remove it once the page is loaded..

```
<body class="loading">
...
</body>
```

and

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){document.body.className = '';};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest / best way would be to use Javascript to do this.  The main way I have seen this implemented is the document ready handler revealing all the hidden stuff.

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('*').show(); });  // Or something similar.
```

Of course, people like to see some sort of feedback of "progress" so your site doesn't appear poorly coded or as if the server is junk.  So a loader bar or whatever.

As I mentioned above, the best place for these types of questions is [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), and perhaps this will be moved over there by a higher-ranked individual.  In the mean time, here is a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435015/how-can-i-make-the-browser-wait-to-display-the-page-until-its-fully-loaded) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: `.ready()` will fire once the DOM is complete, *before* images have loaded, so the OP will continue to have the same problem (i.e., waiting for images to load). From the jQuery docs on `.ready()`: "*In cases where code relies on loaded assets... the code should be placed in a handler for the `load` event instead.*" The OP should wait for `window.onload`.