# Why does code after </html> tag get moved to before </body>? Is there a performance gain?

Tags: html, css, validation, dom, cross-browser

Reading other Stack Overflow posts like [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420697/optimize-css-delivery-a-suggestion-by-google) lead me to [this odd Google recommendation](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery#example) on CSS optimization. "Odd" being their recommendation for deferring CSS loading ended like this:

```
        <div class="blue">Hello, world!</div>
    </body>
</html>
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="small.css"></noscript>
```

Aside from seeming excessive, confusing, having invalid HTML, and stating "The application order of CSS rules is maintained... through javascript." even though there is no javascript shown... my question is this:

When testing their example and inspecting the result, **all the code that occurs after the `</html>` is moved to just before `</body>`.** So my question is... WHY?

1. Why was it moved? It seems like all major browsers try to account for code after `</html>` by moving it to before `</body>`.  I searched for a bit and couldn't find any docs/standards on this.
2. Why would Google even recommend this? As in, is there any actual practical benefit to doing this? Because I would think putting it before the `</body>` to begin with would suffice. (and regarding BoltClock's good subjective explanation, is there any hard evidence that there is in fact a performance gain?)

This occurred in IE11, Firefox 26, Chrome 32.x, and Windows Safari 5.1.7. Inspected HTML was:

```
        <div class="blue">Hello, world!</div>
        <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="small.css"></noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

Adding more code after the `</html>` had the same result.

This reminds me of other odd error-correcting, like how browsers will render `<image>` tags as `<img>` ([ref](http://jakearchibald.com/2013/having-fun-with-image/))...

**UPDATE:** 
For testing, I setup [this URL for NOT deferred CSS](http://mikesmithdev.com/defercss/notdeferred.html) and also [this URL for deferred CSS](http://mikesmithdev.com/defercss/deferred.html) (well, what I expect that article meant)...

Comment: @user2864740 apparently (and yes the source HTML remains the source HTML)... but did browser people think developers are just so bad they are putting code after `</html>` so often that they had to code a fix??

Comment: As far as the DOM, it's [fairly well defined](http://www.w3.org/DOM/) insofar as what elements are allowed where: the browsers do their darnedest to get there. (Other cases of elements being "relocated" is in non-TD elements appearing as children of TR elements.)

Comment: @user2864740 OK I see. And even taking it to the extreme with `<html></html><p>noooo!` will get inspected as fairly valid HTML.

Comment: The result of the *browser* DOM should always be valid HTML - but there is no guarantee that invalid HTML will always result in the same DOM across all browsers.

Comment: @user2864740 exactly... and the root of my question :)

Comment: Missed that :| In any case, I never knew that HTML5 codified a bunch of these previously ill-defined cases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Now that *is* odd. You *aren't* allowed to have *any* elements after the `</html>` end tag because `html` is the root element of an HTML document.

1. But this is HTML, not XHTML. Instead of failing outright (as it would with XHTML), the browser just takes whatever appears at the end of a document (other than comments and I believe whitespace) and moves it to the end of the document body and pretends everything is fine.

   Prior to HTML5, there were no standards for error handling in such cases simply because it's not valid to have any elements after the root element. In HTML5, virtually all error handling is accounted for in [section 8.2.5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#tree-construction). In particular, it states that in the "[after body](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-afterbody)" or "[after after body](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-after-after-body-insertion-mode)" insertion modes, if there's an unexpected token that isn't a DOCTYPE, comment or `</html>` end tag, then the parser should switch the insertion mode to "in body" to process the token, which means whatever is encountered there should be inserted into the body instead. As implied by the names of insertion modes, this means the content gets added to the end of the body.
2. I have no objective answer as to why Google would recommend it, but I do believe Google prioritizes performance over standards compliance, especially in cases where invalid markup is known not to cause serious issues. They're risk-takers like that (see also: Google Chrome), but I digress.

   You mention putting the `noscript` and `link` elements just before the `</body>` end tag, which as you've seen is what ends up happening according to browsers and the HTML5 spec anyway. Keep in mind however that it's not actually valid to have a `link` element in a `noscript` element anywhere outside of the page head in the first place. But again, this is probably a case of performance over standards compliance.

Comment: OK that's pretty much the doc explanation I was hoping for... I know my question #2 is likely unable to be answered, but interested if anyone has input.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev: Heh, I didn't even notice you had listed two questions. Editing my answer to match.

Comment: @BoltClock didn't mean to imply that I would put `link` elements outside of `head`... what I meant was I guess they put it outside of `body`... and even `html` for *some* reason... until today I've never heard of deferred loading of CSS. Just doesn't really make sense to me. I guess perhaps I was expecting a "well it's 9 nanoseconds faster to put it after the ending html tag".

Comment: + thinking about it now I can't see how invalid HTML could be a performance gain over valid HTML. I think the missing piece of the picture is they never actually show the deferred loading of the CSS via javascript (though [this post shows a way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19374984/1810243)). I get deferred loading of JS... but not CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In Simple Words:

If we put something after `</body>`, then that is automatically moved inside the body, at the end, as the HTML spec requires that all content must be inside `<body>`. So there may be no spaces after `</body>`