# DEFER or ASYNC allowed on a stylesheet include?

Tags: html, css, asynchronous, deferred-loading

I know script files can use the DEFER and ASYNC keywords on a resource include. Do these keywords also work for stylesheet (i.e., CSS) includes?

Syntax would presumably be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./path/to/style.css" defer />
```

I just don't know if it's allowed or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS delivery optimization: How to defer css loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374843/css-delivery-optimization-how-to-defer-css-loading)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`Defer` and `Async` are specific attributes of the tag `<script>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

They will not work in other tags, because they don't exist there. A stylesheet is not a script that contains logic to be executed in parallel or after the loading. A stylesheet is a list of static styles that get applied atomically to html.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Yeah, didn't see it on the STYLE page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style

Comment: its possible and mentioned here , https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery

Comment: @youhana - not to be a stickler, but the question is can you use the 'Defer' attribute on a Link element. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link Doesn't use 'defer' attribute. 

The link you provided, is a JS workaround to run the link attribute based on deferred JS. 

It will work, but if someone wasn't careful they'd be misled by your comment. :)

Answer (score 32):

You could do this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" media="none" onload="if(media!=='all')media='all'" >
```

and create a noscript fallback

Comment: what does this do?

Comment: The media attribute only prevents the styles from being applied. Not from being loaded, so this still still loads the .css file on load.

Comment: It's better to use media="print" that exists and is valid.

Comment: Holy Moly! I had a (Roboto font + Material icons) link using `rel=preload` and it was still render blocking a website I was working on. Changed it for this and it jumped from a `90` to a `98` score on Google PageSpeed Insights! Woow!!

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel it will make the styles non-blocking though

Answer (score 19):

**Credit:** https://www.giftofspeed.com/defer-loading-css/

---

Add the following above the closing `</body>` tag of your html document

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* First CSS File */
  var giftofspeed = document.createElement('link');
  giftofspeed.rel = 'stylesheet';
  giftofspeed.href = '../css/yourcssfile.css';
  giftofspeed.type = 'text/css';
  var godefer = document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0];
  godefer.parentNode.insertBefore(giftofspeed, godefer);

  /* Second CSS File */
  var giftofspeed2 = document.createElement('link');
  giftofspeed2.rel = 'stylesheet';
  giftofspeed2.href = '../css/yourcssfile2.css';
  giftofspeed2.type = 'text/css';
  var godefer2 = document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0];
  godefer2.parentNode.insertBefore(giftofspeed2, godefer2);
</script>
```

Comment: Please read carefully the docs, `defer` attribute must not be used if the src attribute is absent, this being the case of the solution proposed

Answer (score 17):

As of Sep 2020 i found that at least Chrome have native support to defer CSS with the attribute `rel="preload"` to make an async load of the file

```
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" rel="preload" as="style">
```

You can use a more comprehensive approach using JavaScript to make it compatible with most browsers and include a `noscript` option when no JS is enabled

```
<link href="main.css" rel="preload" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"></noscript>
```

source: https://web.dev/defer-non-critical-css/

Comment: The first example is wrong; `rel="preload"` is ignored so it's loaded as a regular stylesheet. The second example with `onload` is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find it documented anywhere but my findings are:

**How it was tested**

- Tested **only** with Google Chrome version 61.0.3163.100 (Official version) (64 bits)
- Used Fast & Slow 3G throttling in dev tools.

**What I tested**

I have one stylesheet importing custom fonts and applying the fonts.

**Before:**

Text using the custom font was invisible until it was fully loaded and then it appeared.

**After/Result:**

So added  => Result is that the text is visible immediately when the page is starting to render but using the fallback font, then after a while it switches to the custom font.

**So it seems like at least Google Chrome supports defer on `<link>` tags as well even if it's not documented anywhere publicly...**

Comment: We used this on site.webmanifest link tag... as lighthouse shows it on the critical path.

Answer (score 2):

Lighthouse seems to like this:

```html
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    let link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = "/path/to/style.css";
    document.head.appendChild(link)
  })
</script>
```