# How to remove 'Optimize CSS Delivery' message for my website.

Tags: css

I am using https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/ to determine my page speed. I can see:
**Your page has 11 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.
Approximately 5% of the above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the critical portions of those resources directly in the HTML.**

```
http://jegeachi.com/…in-with-ajax/widget/widget.css?ver=3.1.7
http://jegeachi.com/…-form-validation/css/style.css?ver=4.9.4
http://jegeachi.com/…validation/css/fonts/style.css?ver=4.9.4
http://jegeachi.com/…rontier-post/frontier-post.css?ver=4.4.1
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&ver=4.9.4
http://jegeachi.com/…-and-share/assets/css/styles.css?ver=3.3
http://jegeachi.com/…more-without-refresh/style.css?ver=4.9.4
http://jegeachi.com/…includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.9.4
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/…4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=2.4.2
http://jegeachi.com/…ular-posts/public/css/wpp.css?ver=4.0.13
http://jegeachi.com/…ootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=1.0.1
```

I manually compress all these css files and still I can see same message. What should I do?

N.B: I am using wordpress and Apache server.

Comment: You should start by minifying the files that aren't minified. You're also loading a mix of HTTP and HTTPS traffic, which will create security warnings. Also, this question has been asked at **least** ten times before; you might want to try some of those suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS delivery optimization: How to defer css loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374843/css-delivery-optimization-how-to-defer-css-loading)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [loadCSS](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS) to load your CSS asynchronously in order to avoid render blocking.

`<link rel="preload">` do this for you, but is not supported in all browsers.