# How to add media="print" to all css files except style.css

Tags: wordpress

This is pretty simple to filter a specific css file's link. But I want to filter all except style.css using:  `add_filter( 'style_loader_tag',  'remove_https_http', 10, 4 );` recursively to deliver optimized css and high score on page speed and load time.

```
 add_filter( 'style_loader_tag',  'remove_https_http', 10, 4 );
    function remove_https_styles( $html, $handle, $href, $media ){
        $handles = array('twentysixteen-fonts', 'open-sans');
        if( in_array( $handle, $handles ) ){
            $html = str_replace('https:', '', $html);   
        }
        return $html;
    }
```

This will be great if there is others approach. I already study on: [CSS delivery optimization: How to defer css loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374843/css-delivery-optimization-how-to-defer-css-loading). But it seems to me filtering all css links which can be loaded after rendering my page, suggested by : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-blocking-css.

Any idea will be a great tool tip. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is neither HTML nor CSS. Is it PHP? WordPress?

Comment: update. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following code in functions.php file of the theme.

```
function theme_styles()  
{ 
  // Register the style like this for a theme:  
  // (First the unique name for the style (custom-style) then the src, 
  // then dependencies and ver no. and media type)
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.2', 'print' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');
```

Hope this help and let me know in case of any query.