# How to defer non-critical styles?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, deferred-loading

I am using Chrome DevTools to audit my website. In one of the web pages, it said "Resources are blocking the first paint of your page. Consider delivering critical JS/CSS inline and deferring all non-critical JS/styles. Learn more.". I try to click "Learn More" and go to this article https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/blocking-resources , which said for javascript, one can use defer/async, for css, one can define the media type.

But what if my css is not critical, but it is required for all media types. Then how to defer such a css?

Thanks

Comment: I know that it's possible to defer it using javascript. I don't know if there is a pure HTML solution, probably none that works on all browsers.

Comment: @DanieleTorino, How about using <link rel="prefetch" as="style" href="xxx.css"/> to let the browser know the css is not critical and can be prefetch after the DOM parsing is completed?

Comment: did you get the solution for this? prefetch is helpful but not the solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS delivery optimization: How to defer css loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374843/css-delivery-optimization-how-to-defer-css-loading)

Answer (score 0):

You can place your critical css in the head of your page, it will load before the body part, because css stylesheets are blocking.

And, you can put your non critical css at the end of the body, it will load after all the elements of the DOM.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/critical.css">
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/nonCritical.css">
</body> ...
```

Comment: All <link> CSS is blocking no matter where you place it. It is computed first. It's worst if you put it at the end of the document.

Answer (score 0):

- add critical css to the head section .. like plain css..
- defer all other styles ...
  you may read more from here https://web.dev/defer-non-critical-css/ and look at the example below ..

PS: the best approach from my point of view: is to create some global styles and preload them .. create separate stylesheets for every page/component and insert them into the component itself to be loaded when the component is loaded.

that also depends heavily on the way/tool you are using to build the project ..

```html
<!-- Copyright 2018 Google LLC.
SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0 -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style type="text/css">
      .accordion-btn {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #444;
        background-color: #ADD8E6;
        padding: 19px;
        outline: none;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 2px;
      }

      .container {
        display: none;
        padding: 0 18px;  
        background-color: white;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      h1 {
        word-spacing: 5px;
        color: blue;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
    <link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </noscript>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Critical CSS Demo - Optimized</h1>
    <h3>On this demo, the "critical" styles are inlined, while the non-critical ones, are deferred.</h3>
    <button class="accordion-btn">Click to see a paragraph styled with set of styles #1.</button>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="paragraph1">This is an example of a paragraph that uses <strong>line breaks</strong> for text. This is an example of a paragraph that uses <strong>line breaks</strong> for text. This is an example of a paragraph that uses <strong>line breaks</strong> for text. This is an example of a paragraph that uses <strong>line breaks</strong> for text. This is an example of a paragraph that uses <strong>line breaks</strong> for text. This is an example of a paragraph that uses <strong>line breaks</strong> for text. This is an example of a paragraph that uses <strong>line breaks</strong> for text.</p>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion-btn">Click to see a paragraph styled with set of styles #2.</button>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="paragraph2">This is an example of a paragraph that uses <strong>elipsis</strong> for the overflow text. This is an example of a paragraph that uses <strong>elipsis</strong> for the overflow text. This is an example of a paragraph that uses <strong>elipsis</strong> for the overflow text. This is an example of a paragraph that uses <strong>elipsis</strong> for the overflow text.</p>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion-btn">Click to see a paragraph styled with set of styles #3.</button>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="paragraph3">This is an example of a paragraph that <strong>trims text</strong>. This is an example of a paragraph that <strong>trims text</strong>. This is an example of a paragraph that <strong>trims text</strong>. This is an example of a paragraph that <strong>trims text</strong>. This is an example of a paragraph that <strong>trims text</strong>. This is an example of a paragraph that <strong>trims text</strong>.</p>
    </div>
    <script>
    var accordionBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-btn");

    for (let i = 0; i < accordionBtn.length; i++) {
        accordionBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            var container = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (container.style.display === "block") {
                container.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                container.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```