# Async or defer (or delay) CSS load

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I'm working on my site speed score and trying to improve my Pagespeed (Remove unused CSS report).

First I have followed this page: [load CSS simpler](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/load-css-simpler/) and I have deferred the following way but page speed keeps alerting me that the `/css/second-style` CSS file is not deferred:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/second-style.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'">
```

So, I have tried another way, using: [loadCSS](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS), I have done it this way:

```
<script src="loadCSS.js"></script>
<script>
  loadCSS( "/css/second-style.css" );
</script>
```

I think the two ways of doing it are quite clear and simple, and they are supposed to work but page speed does not approve `/css/second-style.css`.

Any idea if in 2021 it has to be done differently or what is my mistake?
Is there another way to delay the CSS load?

Comment: Not sure if delaying CSS is the right way to go. What a "Remove unused CSS report" is saying is that your CSS contains styles that are not used on the page. Try to split your CSS into parts that _are_ used on the page, inline those styles and load the rest via an external CSS file.

Comment: @brombeer Yes, I understand, even so, if I make these CSS loads at the end of the page load (delaying them), there would be no problem even if they are "unused CSS".

Comment: Then move them to the end?  Just before `</body>` perhaps.  I don't know if that would affect the site speed score or if it will still say you have unused css.

Comment: @freedomn-m yes, if I put there the problem still persists :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS delivery optimization: How to defer css loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374843/css-delivery-optimization-how-to-defer-css-loading)

Answer (score 0):

Even though u load the CSS last or in the beginning the total load time will be the same..
Try [minifying CSS](http://www.minifycss.com/css-compressor/) and make it single file(There by reduce the number of request)

To increase speed more you can also try [Compressing JavaScript](http://javascriptcompressor.com/) and [HTML](https://www.textfixer.com/html/compress-html-compression.php)
and also [Image sprit](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Comment: Yes, the "total" load will be the same, but the *perceived* load time will not be the same.