# how to load background Image progressively as received?

Tags: css, background-image, progressive

I have a 635 KB JPG file as background and It does not get displayed until the page is loaded.

That is making my website look ugly as soon as someone hits it.

How do I make it load progressively as received?

My css is

```
html {
        background: url(img/1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Comment: You may show the "Loading" message only until page get loaded. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435015/how-can-i-make-the-browser-wait-to-display-the-page-until-its-fully-loaded

Comment: [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/12/progressive-image-rendering.html) is how a guy is doing but he said try it for myself

Comment: this will help you http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2008/12/05/imageopt-4/

Comment: he just explains the difference, He says it is a default action, but my website does not load it as baseline image. I am using firefox.