# Page jumps a few pixels when loading

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have noticed that my website jumps a few pixels when loading... been trying to figure out why but I am at an end. If someone could help me figure this out it would be appreciated. It is really noticable on the All In One Map Link. Here is Link to site:   [MoreOutdoors.net](http://moreoutdoors.net/)

Comment: good luck getting people to click outbound links here. jsfiddle.net is typically accepted. Without looking though, are you sure it's not the browser adding a scrollbar in? typically that's the jump most people are referring to

Comment: I didn't know any other way of trying to figure out the problem. I can not recreate it on jsfiddle since it is a styling issue with the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jump is the browsers vertical scroll bar appearing while the page is loading.

Try adding this to your css:

```
html {
       overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This will force the vertical scrollbar to appear at the start of the page load.

Another alternative would be to not show anything until the page is loaded.  It's not advisable but you'll find more information here:
[How can I make the browser wait to display the page until it's fully loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435015/how-can-i-make-the-browser-wait-to-display-the-page-until-its-fully-loaded)

Comment: Thank you for that it worked. I like it simple and easy. Question solved... wish I could vote you up but I don't have enough reputation yet.