# Primefaces loading data message when open new page

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, xhtml

My scenario is the following:

I have a jsp page which calls through a function "**`window.open`**" an xhtml page that retrieve some data. As the query to `DDBB` takes a little bit, I would like to add to the xhtml page (which is actually void until data is loaded) some kind of message like "`Loading data`".

I like how Primefaces `blockUI` component works for same page when you click on a button but in my case I don't have any... the xhtml page it's just for showing some details from DDBB.

Do you have any idea about how can I do it? I was thinking that Primefaces has for sure some easy way to do it but I cannot find it :-P

Thanks in advance to you all!

All my best,

Carlos

Comment: Pf Progress Bar can be a solution of your problem but it would call when some ajax request will happen http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/progressBar.xhtml .From JS how could you call that you have to check.

Comment: I see nothing PF related or even JSF related in your question. Hence I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853662/how-to-show-page-loading-div-until-the-page-has-finished-loading is a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

One example is here,we generally show a progress image for any ajax request and code be like this

```
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()" onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide()" />
<p:dialog id="progressImage" widgetVar="statusDialog" modal="true" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false">
 <p:graphicImage value="../resources/images/spin-loader.gif" />
</p:dialog>
```

Now same think you can call from Javascript function as well

```
function callProgessBar() {

         PF('statusDialog').show();
}
```

Comment: Hello @Subodh Joshi 
I think this requires a button who call the dialog...
I was thinking more something like:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435015/how-can-i-make-the-browser-wait-to-display-the-page-until-its-fully-loaded]
but for primefaces.
I want to show a message or something until the page its fully loaded

Comment: How you calling Window.open same way you can call Javascript method as well.